# Django REST framework object level permissions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-permissions

I am using Django REST Framework to access a resource 'user'.

As user information is personal, I do not want a GET request to list every user on the system, UNLESS they are an admin.

If the user specifies their id, and they are logged in, I would like them to be able to view their details and amend them (PUT POST DELETE) if required.

So in summary, dis-allow GET method for anyone who isn't an admin and allow GET POST DELETE PUT on logged-in users when viewing their information.

I created the custom permission class:

```
class UserPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Owners of the object or admins can do anything.
    Everyone else can do nothing.
"""
    
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # if admin: True otherwise False
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # if request.user is the same user that is contained within the obj then allow
```

This didn't work. After some debugging I found that it checks `has_permission` first, THEN checks `has_object_permission`. So if we don't get past that first hurdle GET `/user/`, then it won't even consider the next GET `/user/id`.

How I would go about getting this to work?

I was using ModelViewSets.

But if you split the List functionality with the Detail then you can give them separate permission classes:

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes=(UserPermissionsAll,)

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes=(UserPermissionsObj,)

class UserPermissionsAll(permissions.BasePermission):
"""
Owners of the object or admins can do anything.
Everyone else can do nothing.
"""

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_staff:
            return True
        else:
            return False

class UserPermissionsObj(permissions.BasePermission):
"""
Owners of the object or admins can do anything.
Everyone else can do nothing.
"""

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user.is_staff:
            return True

        return obj == request.user
```

Comment: The solution below from Chemical Programmer will work with `viewsets`.

Answer (score 23):

I have done this in the past using a custom permission and overridden [`has_object_permission`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) like the following:

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class MyUserPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Handles permissions for users.  The basic rules are

     - owner may GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
     - nobody else can access
     """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        # check if user is owner
        return request.user == obj
```

You can do some more detailed things such as deny specific request types (for instance to allow a GET requests for all users):

```
class MyUserPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        # Allow get requests for all
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return True
        return request.user == obj
```

Then in your view you tell it to use the permissions class:

```
from my_custom_permissions import MyUserPermissions

class UserView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ...
    permission_classes = (MyUserPermissions, )
    ...
```

Answer (score 14):

I have a similar need. Lets call my app `x`. Here's what I came up with.

First, put this in `x/viewsets.py`:

```
# viewsets.py
from rest_framework import mixins, viewsets

class DetailViewSet(
  mixins.CreateModelMixin,
  mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
  mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
  mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
  viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    pass

class ReadOnlyDetailViewSet(
  mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
  viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    pass

class ListViewSet(
  mixins.ListModelMixin,
  viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    pass
```

Then in `x/permissions.py`:

```
# permissions.py
from rest_framework import permissions

class UserIsOwnerOrAdmin(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()

    def check_object_permission(self, user, obj):
        return (user and user.is_authenticated() and
          (user.is_staff or obj == user))

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return self.check_object_permission(request.user, obj)
```

Then in `x/views.py`:

```
# views.py
from x.viewsets import DetailViewSet, ListViewSet
from rest_framework import permissions

class UserDetailViewSet(DetailViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = (UserIsOwnerOrAdmin,)

class UserViewSet(ListViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes (permissions.IsAdminUser,)
```

By the way, notice that you can use a ***different serializer*** for those two viewsets, which means you can show different attributes in the `list` view than in the `retrieve` view! For example:

```
# serializers.py
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'url',)

class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'groups', 'profile', 'password',)
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
```

Then in `x/urls.py`:

```
# urls.py
from x import views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserDetailViewSet)

...
```

I was mildly surprised that `router` accepted the same pattern twice, but it does appear to work.

Caveat lector: I've confirmed this all works via the API browser, but I haven't tried ***updating*** via the API yet.

Comment: I like this approach, you don't even need to create intermediate classes like DetailViewSet or ListViewSet. And it makes defining permissions much easier.

Answer (score 11):

Just one more thing to @will-hart's answer.

In DRF3 documentation,

> Note: The instance-level has_object_permission method will only be called if the view-level has_permission checks have already passed

Therefore, **`has_permission` should be specified** to use `has_object_permission`.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class MyUserPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user == obj
```

---

However, above code will give permission to anyone when user tries to get list of user. In this case, it would be better to **give permission according to `action`, not the `HTTP method`**.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

def has_permission(self, request, view):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return True
    elif view.action == 'retrieve':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return True
    elif view.action == 'retrieve':
        return obj == request.user or request.user.is_staff
```

Comment: For defining complex permissions, this is kind of a nightmare. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 10):

For the stumble-upons, the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) under limitations of object level permission says:

> For performance reasons the generic views will not automatically apply object level permissions to each instance in a queryset when returning a list of objects.

So, details view will work but for the list, you'll need to [filter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) against the current user.

Comment: [`django-rest-framework-guardian`](https://github.com/rpkilby/django-rest-framework-guardian) is one option to help automatically filter if you are using [`django-guardian`](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian).

Answer (score 1):

This is a clarification on overriding the has_object_permission() method. Returning False wouldn't work as intended when using complex permissions.
Refer to this issue for more details
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/7117

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. The problem was the order of the permissions when using the `|` operator. The first permissions should be the ones with `has_object_permission` method, and this method should call `has_permission` for the permissions which don't implement it.